# Fitting Methods in Arima

Tags: r, time-series, arima

Could someone please explain the differences between the 3 fitting methods, method = c("CSS-ML", "ML", "CSS"), in Arima?  If I run the code below I get an error message, but if I specify method="ML" in Arima it runs fine.  So I was curious what the difference was between the 3 fitting methods.

Code with error:

```
library("fpp")

tsTrain <- window(hsales,end=1989.99)

pvar<-1:10
dvar<-1:2
qvar<-1:7

OrderGrid<-expand.grid(pvar,dvar,qvar)

n <- function(a,b,c) {Arima(tsTrain, order=c(a,b,c))}
ModFit <- do.call(Vectorize(n, SIMPLIFY=FALSE), unname(OrderGrid))
```

Fixed Code:

```
library("fpp")

tsTrain <- window(hsales,end=1989.99)

pvar<-1:10
dvar<-1:2
qvar<-1:7

OrderGrid<-expand.grid(pvar,dvar,qvar)

n <- function(a,b,c) {Arima(tsTrain, order=c(a,b,c),method="ML")}
ModFit <- do.call(Vectorize(n, SIMPLIFY=FALSE), unname(OrderGrid))
```

Comment: Have you tried the help file first and then some time series textbook (e.g. Hamilton's) for further detail?

Answer (score 5):

According to the documentation, this is how each method fits the model:

- `CSS` minimises the sum of squared residuals.
- `ML` maximises the log-likelihood function of the ARIMA model.
- `CSS-ML` mixes both methods: first, `CSS` is run, the starting parameters for the optimization algorithm are set to zeros or to the values given in the optional argument `init`; then, `ML` is applied passing the `CSS` parameter estimates as starting parameter values for the optimization algorithm.

In a model with lags of the dependent variable, a initial set of observations must be somehow defined in order to evaluate the sum of squares or the likelihood function. `CSS` and `ML` deal with this issue differently. `CSS` sets the initial observations to zeros, while `ML` uses the initial state vector returned by the Kalman filter. `ML` is supposed to be more accurate since, instead of setting these initial observations to zeros, it uses the sample data in order to get an estimate of these values.

For some details about the initialisation of the Kalman filter you may see 
[this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/202903/start-up-values-for-the-kalman-filter) or 
[this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/209080/how-is-the-first-residual-calculated-in-a-fitted-ar1-model).

Notice that one thing is the starting parameter values and another is the set of initial observations. The former can be specified through the argument `init`, while the latter are specified internally by each method as described before. This distinction is important in order to not get confused when reading the documentation.

---

In your code, the following error is obtained for the ARIMA(10,1,2) model:

```
Error in optim(init[mask], armafn, method = optim.method, hessian = TRUE,  : 
  non-finite finite-difference value [5]
```

Roughly, this means that the optimization algorithm failed to reach a result.
The error arises for `method="ML"` (actually for the `ML` step of the `CSS-ML` method). A further insight shows that the initial parameter values obtained from `CSS` are apparently not good enough. The following gives error:

```
arima(tsTrain, order=c(10,1,2), method="CSS-ML")
```

while using zeros (the default) as starting parameters the optimization algorithm converges to a solution:

```
arima(tsTrain, order=c(10,1,2), method="ML")
```

At first glance, this may seem strange, since the `CSS` step is supposed to provide starting parameters relatively close to those that maximise the likelihood function. A look at the autocorrelations of the data `acf(tsTrain); pacf(tsTrain)` suggests that the model ARIMA(10,1,2) is not plausible for the data, in fact this model is far from the model chosen by `forecast::auto.arima`, ARMA(1,0,0)(2,0,0). This may explain why estimates from `CSS` were not reliable as input for `ML`.